# Magento uploading large resolution images will be compressed

Tags: magento2

The magento version I am using is **2.1.5**

Uploading product images on the product image upload interface will be compressed.

> **For example:** I uploaded a **4000*5119** resolution image size of **659kb**. After uploading, the file size will be compressed to **66kb**, and the resolution will be compressed to **937*1200.**

How can I not compress it?